# Bootstrap 4 usage is not responsive to foreground img

Tags: html, css

I have an image [sample](http://via.placeholder.com/1600x1600) which shows on the following html page. A fellow commenter named Em An helped with putting the [sample](http://via.placeholder.com/1600x1600) on the page and I thought my solution was solved. But replacing the [sample](http://via.placeholder.com/1600x1600) with this [Word cloud image](https://github.com/hilsdsg3/MovieBuddy/blob/master/meta_data/word_cloud_graphic.png) does not work. The word cloud image shows as a broken image in the HTML. It is not the format of the image as a png because i exported the image as a jpg and it still does not show.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```css
/*
 * Globals
 */

/* Links */
a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Custom default button */
.btn-secondary,
.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-secondary:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none; /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: .05rem solid #fff;
}


.loading-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.loading-overlay > .inner
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


body{
  top-margin:60px;
}
.heading{
  font-size:400%;
}
.background{
  background-color:lightgrey;
  margin-top:5rem;
}
#word1{
  margin-top:1rem;
  margin-bottom:1rem;
  color:black;
}

/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {
  /* The image used */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("img/word_cloud_background_br.jpg");

  /* Full height */

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.cover-container {
  max-width: 42em;
}

#sel1{
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}

/*
 * Header
 */
.masthead {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.masthead-brand {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link {
  padding: .25rem 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(532, 255, 255, .5);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: .25rem solid transparent;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link + .nav-link {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-masthead .active {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-masthead {
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
 * Cover
 */
.cover {
  padding: 0 rem;
}

/* Doesnt work!! 
h1.cover-heading {
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
  font-size: 10em;
  color: red;
}
*/

.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

/*
 * Footer
 */
.mastfoot {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

/* start update */
html, body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: auto !important;
}
.container-image {
  position: relative;
  max-width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
.container-image .image-floating {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 0;
  width: 50vw;
  max-width: 600px;
}
@media(max-width: 600px) {
  .container-image .image-floating  {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>WordCloud</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/cover/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="static/css/assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
      
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="static/wc.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container container-image"> 
      
      <img class="image-floating" src="https://github.com/hilsdsg3/MovieBuddy/blob/master/meta_data/word_cloud_graphic.png" />
      <!--<img class="image-floating" src="//via.placeholder.com/1600x1600" />-->
      <br>
      <h2>Select from one of the word clouds</h2>
      <form action="/action_page.php">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="sel1">  </label>
          <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="sellist1">
                <option value="woman_director" selected>Woman Director</option>
                <option value="murder">Murder</option>
                <option value="based_on_novel">Based on a Novel</option>
                <option value="musical">Musical</option>
                <option value="sex">Sex</option>
                <option value="biography">Biography</option>
                <option value="nudity">Nudity</option>
                <option value="revenge">Revenge</option>
                <option value="suspense">Suspense</option>
                <option value="love">Love</option>
                <option value="female nudity">REMOVE</option>
                <option value="sport">Sport</option>
                <option value="police">Police</option>
                <option value="sequel">Sequel</option>
                <option value="teenager">Teen</option>
                <option value="duringcreditsstinger">REMOVE</option>
                <option value="world_war_ii">World War II</option>
                <option value="stand">REMOVE</option>
                <option value="drug">Drug</option>
                <option value="prison">Prison</option>
                <option value="up_comedy">Comedy</option>
                <option value="high_school">High School</option>
                <option value="martial_arts">Martial Arts</option>
                <option value="family">Family</option>
                <option value="suicide">Suicide</option> 
                <option value="film_noir">Film Noir</option>
                <option value="rape">Rape</option>
                <option value="kidnapping">Kidnapping</option>
                <option value="silent_film">Silent Film</option>
                <option value="serial_killer">Serial Killer</option>
                <option value="monster">Monster</option>
                <option value="alien">Alien</option>
                <option value="parts">REMOVE</option>
                <option value="dystophia">Apocalypse</option>
                <option value="new_york">New York</option>
                <option value="gay">Gay</option>
                <option value="short">REMOVE</option>
                <option value="blood">Blood</option>
                <option value="marriage">Marriage</option>
                <option value="gore">Gore</option>
                <option value="zombie">Zombie</option>
                <option value="death">Death</option>
                <option value="gangster">Gangster</option>
                <option value="small_town">Small Town</option>
                <option value="london_england">London England</option>
                <option value="romance">Romance</option>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-image: url(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/assets/img/bootstrap-themes.png);">
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is working when when you use `img-fluid`. I've added your original code to a runnable snippet  - if you edit it and change `img-responsive` to `img-fluid` you can see it working. If its not working in your project then something else in you code is affecting it.

Comment: Have you tried to put your img into a box?

Comment: No. I am sorry I don't really know how to do that. I would like to know why a simple  image replacement does not work from the 1600x1600 image to my word_cloud image.

Comment: Is this still an issue ? Looking at below answer looks like you got the answer

Comment: Unfortunately, Em An was fitting the 1600x1600 black image. This works fine. But It was not the image that I wanted. I wanted the wordcloud.png. I was not clear with her so it is my fault. The 1600x1600 image shows up but when I changed the image to the wordcloud, it appears broken and I don't know why. I edited my question with my current code. https://github.com/hilsdsg3/MovieBuddy/blob/master/meta_data/word_cloud_graphic.png" ----- DOESN'T WORK
//via.placeholder.com/1600x1600 ----- WORKS

Comment: The reason it doesn't work with that image is because it is **not a valid image url**! When you click on that link it goes to a github *page*, not directly to the image itself thie link to the image is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hilsdsg3/MovieBuddy/master/meta_data/word_cloud_graphic.png. If you replace the broken link with this or any valid image link it works e.g. you can also try https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/1600x900 or https://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1600-1400-2.jpg

Comment: Yes, that was it. thank you. Would you enter your explanation in an answer so you can be awarded with the bounty ? or is that not how a bounty works ?

Comment: You should award the bounty to @EmAn because that is the real answer to your question - my comment about the link was to do with your misunderstanding of what the link was pointing to, and issues arising from mistypes are off topic on Stack Overflow so I won't add an answer because I don't think it is right to get the bounty for an off-topic answer when you already got the real one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works well with an external image, so the actual problem was a mistype. In the below example there is a small change in `CSS`.

```css
/*
 * Globals
 */


/* Links */

a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}


/* Custom default button */

.btn-secondary,
.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-secondary:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none;
  /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: .05rem solid #fff;
}

.loading-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.loading-overlay>.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

body {
  top-margin: 60px;
}

.heading {
  font-size: 400%;
}

.background {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

#word1 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: black;
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {
  /* The image used */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("img/word_cloud_background_br.jpg");
  /* Full height */
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.cover-container {
  max-width: 42em;
}

#sel1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}


/*
 * Header
 */

.masthead {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.masthead-brand {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link {
  padding: .25rem 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(532, 255, 255, .5);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: .25rem solid transparent;
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link+.nav-link {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav-masthead .active {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-masthead {
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
 * Cover
 */

.cover {
  padding: 0 rem;
}


/* Doesnt work!! 
h1.cover-heading {
  font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
  font-size: 10em;
  color: red;
}
*/

.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}


/*
 * Footer
 */

.mastfoot {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}


/* start update */

html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: auto !important;
}

.container-image {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100vw - 100px);
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-content: space-evenly;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.container-image .image-floating {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

@media(max-width: 600px) {
  .container-image .image-floating {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/cover/">

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="static/css/assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="static/wc.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container container-image">

  <img class="image-floating" src="https://picsum.photos/1600/1600" />
  <br>
  <h2>Select from one of the word clouds</h2>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1">  </label>
      <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="sellist1">
        <option value="woman_director" selected>Woman Director</option>
        <option value="murder">Murder</option>
        <option value="based_on_novel">Based on a Novel</option>
        <option value="musical">Musical</option>
        <option value="sex">Sex</option>
        <option value="biography">Biography</option>
        <option value="nudity">Nudity</option>
        <option value="revenge">Revenge</option>
        <option value="suspense">Suspense</option>
        <option value="love">Love</option>
        <option value="female nudity">REMOVE</option>
        <option value="sport">Sport</option>
        <option value="police">Police</option>
        <option value="sequel">Sequel</option>
        <option value="teenager">Teen</option>
        <option value="duringcreditsstinger">REMOVE</option>
        <option value="world_war_ii">World War II</option>
        <option value="stand">REMOVE</option>
        <option value="drug">Drug</option>
        <option value="prison">Prison</option>
        <option value="up_comedy">Comedy</option>
        <option value="high_school">High School</option>
        <option value="martial_arts">Martial Arts</option>
        <option value="family">Family</option>
        <option value="suicide">Suicide</option>
        <option value="film_noir">Film Noir</option>
        <option value="rape">Rape</option>
        <option value="kidnapping">Kidnapping</option>
        <option value="silent_film">Silent Film</option>
        <option value="serial_killer">Serial Killer</option>
        <option value="monster">Monster</option>
        <option value="alien">Alien</option>
        <option value="parts">REMOVE</option>
        <option value="dystophia">Apocalypse</option>
        <option value="new_york">New York</option>
        <option value="gay">Gay</option>
        <option value="short">REMOVE</option>
        <option value="blood">Blood</option>
        <option value="marriage">Marriage</option>
        <option value="gore">Gore</option>
        <option value="zombie">Zombie</option>
        <option value="death">Death</option>
        <option value="gangster">Gangster</option>
        <option value="small_town">Small Town</option>
        <option value="london_england">London England</option>
        <option value="romance">Romance</option>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container" style="background-image: url(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/assets/img/bootstrap-themes.png);">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use class img-fluid instead of img-reponsive

Comment: Tried that too. Doesn't work. I am using a hard refresh on chrome cntrl+shift+R

Comment: Kindly go to this example:
https://codepen.io/Em-An/pen/zYqWvqX

Comment: Thank you. It worked in code pen but I can't get it to work in mine. Do you think my CSS stylesheet is overriding it ?     <link href="static/wc.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: I am ready to put in your PC to fix it (Team Viewer OR AnyDesk) Call me on my email in an half hour - study.eman@gmail.com

Comment: try this:  .center-block {max-width:100% !important}

Comment: Tried it , it doesn't work. I have installed teamviewer.  I am not sure how to call you with an email. It gives a conf number with a fee.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221228/discussion-between-paul-and-em-an).

Comment: Em An is awesome. She did the perfect job.